# Mock Animation running out of memory

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, uiimage, nstimer

I am trying to simulated animation based on a series of 54 images.  I am getting an - "Program received signal:  “0”." message - running out of memory.

I am trying my best to take care of them by I seem to be failing.  I am running through all 54 in about 4-5 seconds, and then it should repeat (almost like a flip book).  The animation is not something that can easily be done using Core animation due to the shiny 3D material in the image.

Or, is there better way of going about this?

Here is the code:

```
-(void)addImage:(NSString*)imageName{
    if (self.images == nil){
        self.images = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    [self.images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
}

// Returns a UIImageView that contains the next image to display
- (UIImageView *)nextImageView
{
    // get the image at the next index
    UIImage *image = [images objectAtIndex:pictureIndex];
    ++pictureIndex; // increment the index

    if(pictureIndex > images.count -1){
        pictureIndex = 0;
    }


    // create an image view for the image
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    // resize the image to fill the screen without distorting
    imageView.frame = rotator.frame;

    imageView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];


    // Makes the image move proportionally in any direction if the
    // bounds of the superview change when the iPhone is rotated.
    imageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |                          
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |                            
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

    return imageView;
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)_timer{
    UIImageView *nextImageView = [self nextImageView];
    if(nextImageView){
        [self.view addSubview:nextImageView];
        nextImageView.alpha = 0.0;

        //NSLog(@"timerFired - image no: %i", pictureIndex);

        // begin animation block
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nextImageView];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration]; // set the animation length
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; // set the animation delegate

        // call the given method when the animation ends
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(transitionFinished:finished:context:)];

        // make the next image appear with the chosen effect
        [nextImageView setAlpha:1.0]; // fade in the next image
        [currentImageView setAlpha:0.0]; // fade out the old image

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }

}

// called when the image transition animation finishes
- (void)transitionFinished:(NSString *)animationId finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context
{
    [currentImageView removeFromSuperview]; // remove the old image
    [currentImageView release]; // release the memory for the old image
    currentImageView = context; // assign the new image
}

-(void)startRotator{
    self.rotator.animationImages = self.images;
    self.rotator.animationDuration = animationDuration;

    pictureIndex = 0; // reset the index

    currentImageView = [self nextImageView]; // load the first image
    [self.view addSubview:currentImageView]; // add the image to the view

    //[self.rotator startAnimating];
    NSLog(@"start Animating - Image Count: %i", self.images.count);

    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:scheduledInterval 
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timerFired:) 
                                           userInfo:nil 
                                            repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are leaking `imageView` in `nextImageView`. The returned instance should be autoreleased.

Are you sure your 54 images fit into memeory?

Comment: Also bear in mind that most image formats are stored uncompressed in the iPhone's memory, so they may be taking up more memory than you realise.  iOS can store PVRTC images compressed in memory, but they've got tradeoffs of their own.

Comment: It is getting released in transitionFinished.  I was able to shrink them all down and that seemed to do the trick.  Can you tell me more about PVRTC?